# Exception Handling Try-catch: What happens if var 1 , 2 , and 3 are false

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, runtime-error

I need to trace through the following code. What happens?
I got this far...

Let's start  (now try f)
F begins  next throw Exc1 since var1 = false
NOw do I return to try in main and go to method d?

```
void main() {
    println("Let's start");
    try {
        f();
        d();
    } catch (Ex1 ex) {
        println("main caught Ex1");
    } catch (Ex3 ex) {
        println("main caught Ex3");
    } finally {
        println("main finally");
    }
    println("main end");
}

void f() {
    println("F begins");
    try {
        if (var1) {
            d();
        } else {
            throw new Ex1();
        }
    } catch (Ex2 ex) {
        println("f caught Ex2");
    }
    println("a end");
}

void d() {
    println("d begin");
    try {
        if (var2) throw new Ex2();
        if (var3) throw new Ex3();
    } catch (Ex3 ex) {
        println("d caught ex3");
    } finally {
        println("d finally");
    }
    println("d end");
}
```

Comment: you don't have a b() you have a d()

Comment: yes it is calling d(). I am confused with the "flow"

Comment: So far.. I see the program printing  "Let's start", going to f(), "F begins", try statement var1 = false so proceed to else, throw Exc1(), return to main, go to d, "d begin", printing "d finally", going to main, main catches ex1, "main catches Exc1", "main finally", "main end". IS THIS CORRECT?

Comment: ^ yes lol that is all it does

Comment: If you want to see the exact path being followed when the exception is thrown, use the printStackTrace() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
try {
    f();
    d();
} catch (Ex1 ex) {
    println("main caught Ex1");
} catch (Ex3 ex) {
    println("main caught Ex3");
} finally {
    println("main finally");
}
```

If `f()` throws an exception, the `try` block will quit.  Whether or not the exception is caught, `main()` will **not** call `d()`.  If there's a `catch` block that catches the exception, it will be executed and then the `finally` block is executed; otherwise, the `finally` block is executed and then the exception is thrown again.  But in both cases, `d()` will not be called.

Comment: thanks! So the main method's try statement will automatically catch Ex1 and then print and end the program?

Comment: @StreamingBits Thats what I see happening, f() throws Ex1, which is not caught by the try in f(), hence it propagates up to the main methods try, which catches it in catch(Ex1 ex), prints to screen, finally runs, then program exit.

Comment: @Mark W Thanks. I am new to this and I want to make sure I am not missing something dumb. Just a concept question.

Comment: @ajb SO if f didn't throw an exception, then it would go to d()?

Comment: @StreamingBits Right.  If `f()` doesn't throw an exception, then it returns to `main()` normally, and then `main()` calls `d()` as normal.  Note that if `f()` does throw an exception, but then `f()` itself catches it and doesn't re-throw it, then `f()` will also return to `main()` normally, and then `main()` will call `d()`.